# Basic topology: Checking if a family defines a topology on X

Tags: general-topology

Let X be any set

$T_f :=\{U\in X, X\setminus U$ is finite or equal to X$\}$

In order to check if it is indeed a topology on X I have to check the 3 following properties:

(1): $\emptyset , X \in T_f$

(2): $U_i \in T_f \forall i \in I \implies \cup_{i\in I} U_i \in T_f$

(3): $U_1, U_2 \in T_f \implies U_1 \cap U_2 \in T_f $

I know for a fact that it defines a topology on X, I now have to prove it

Now proving (1) is easy but when I try to prove (2) I encounter a problem:

- In the case where X is finite, then since $U_i \in X$ any $U$ is finite, therefore $\cup_{i\in I} U_i$ is finite and $X \setminus \cup_{i\in I} U_i$ is finite. therefore $\cup_{i\in I} U_i \in T_f$
- But in the case where X is not finite I encounter a problem, indeed, $X/\cup_{i\in I} U_i$ will always be infinite except if $\cup_{i\in I} U_i = X$ or $\emptyset$. therefore in this case $\cup_{i\in I} U_i \notin T_f$

But I know that $T_f$ defines a topology on $X$. How do I cope with this problem?

Comment: I think you mean $U \subseteq X$, not $U \in X$. Does this help ?

Comment: If you throw out more sets from $X$, it gets smaller (more finite)

Comment: The point is that $X - U$ is finite not that $U$ is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proof of $2$:

Suppose $U_i\in X$ if $U_i=\varnothing$ for some $i$ we are done, otherwise we have that $X\setminus U_i$ is finite for each $i$. We must prove that $X\setminus\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}U_i$ is finite.

But by De'Morgan's laws we have $X\setminus\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}U_i=\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}(X\setminus U_i)$.

This set is clearly finite as it is the intersection of finite sets is finite.

In fact, the co-finite topology has the interesting property that the union of any family of sets that contains at least one open set is open.

Comment: why are we allowed to suppose that any U is finite?

Comment: we are not, but we can assume $X\setminus U$ is finite

Comment: Also how can you prove that  $X \setminus U_i$ is finite. For instance, if X and all $U_i$ are finite then it would seem that $\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}(X\setminus U_i) $ is infinite

Comment: But isn't the proof unfinished then?

Comment: the intersection of finite sets is finite.

Comment: I don't understand why $X\setminus U_i$ is finished. I we take the following example: $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $U_1 = (0,1) U_2=(1,2), U_3=(2,3)$ then $X\setminus\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}U_i$ is not finitee.

Comment: I think you mean finite, but $U_1,U_2,U_3$ are not open, in your example.

Comment: I changed my example

Comment: But those sets are not open when you consider your topology on $\mathbb R$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I only had one topology class so far. Thank you I somehow forgot that $X \setminus U_i$ had to be finite since $U_i \in T_f$

Comment: No problem, happy to help.